# selecting text in quotes

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I select the text found in double quotes?

```
# cat list.txt
File "abc.txt" not found.
```

I want to return only abc.txt
I am not sure which is the best tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all text within double quotes, try this.

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"' list.txt
```

The single quotes are to prevent the pattern from the shell; the actual pattern says to match a double quote, followed by a sequence of characters which are not double quote, followed by another double quote.  The `-o` option to `grep` says to only print the matches (the default is to print the whole line when there is a match on the pattern).

Comment: And I do also want to remove the double quotes. So instead of "abc.txt" it should return abc.txt only

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nle'print $1 while /"([^"]*)"/g' list.txt
```

With *GNU grep* if you have one occurrence per line:

```
grep -Po '(?<=")[^"]*(?=")'  list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  echo 'File "abc.txt" not found.'|sed -r 's/.*"([^"]*)".*/\1/g'
abc.txt
```

Comment: This will only extract the first occurrence if there are several.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'File "abc.txt" not found.' | awk '{print substr($2,2,length($2)-2)}'
```